# How to get user name from user id in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hellow i want to show 10 persons who has deposited and withdraw amount in last24 hours . i am able to show there user_id and amount but i want users name instead of user_id.

It is working for fund not for withdraw

i have no name colum in $funds and $withdrae it is in users i have this code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="text-center"><h4 class="text-success">Last 10 Investors</h4></div>
<table class="table text-white" >
    <tbody>
        @foreach( \App\Fund::where('created_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subHours(24))->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(10)->get() as $fund)
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"></th>
            <td>{{ $fund->user_id }}</td>
            <td class="text-center text-warning">{{ $fund->total }}</td>
            <td class="text-right"><img src="https://adsok.com/img/btc.png" alt="Bitcoin"> <i><b>bitcoin</b></i><br></td><br>
        </tr>@endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>
```

.

For withdraw

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="text-center"><h4 class="text-success">Last 10 Investors</h4></div>
<table class="table text-white" >
    <tbody>
        @foreach( \App\Withdraw::where('created_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subHours(24))->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(10)->get() as $withdraw)
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"></th>
            <td>{{ $withdraw->user_id }}</td>
            <td class="text-center text-warning">{{ $withdraw->total }}</td>
            <td class="text-right"><img src="https://adsok.com/img/btc.png" alt="Bitcoin"> <i><b>bitcoin</b></i><br></td><br>
        </tr>@endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>
```

.

I have pasted same relationship in both fund and withdraw model

```
 public function user()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');}
```

Comment: If you already set the user relation, you could call the user data with `$fund->user->id` or `$fund->user->name`. As described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).

Answer (score 0):

Add `with('user')` to the query:

```
Fund::with('user')->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subHours(24))->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(10)->get()
```

Then you'll be able to show user name:

```
{{ $fund->user->name }}
```

Also, [do not run any queries in Blade templates](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#do-not-execute-queries-in-blade-templates-and-use-eager-loading-n--1-problem), it's a bad practice.

Comment: @WaqarAli what exactly is not working? Do you have any error? If not, please add the results of `{{ dd(\App\Fund::with('user')->where('created_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subHours(24))->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(10)->get()) }}` to your question.

Comment: It's says trying to get property of non object

Comment: @WaqarAli if this code causes the error, it means some of the funds do not have a user. Maybe the error is caused by some other code. Please show results of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Withdraw` and `Fund` model should have a `belongsTo` relationship to your `User` model.

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\User", "user_id", "id");
}
```

Then whenever you try to access a `User` related to a `Fund`, you can simply do

```
$fund->user->name
```

But there can be chances where `Fund` does not have any related `User`, so you need to check it's existence before accessing its attributes.

```
$fund->user ? $fund->user->name : "na"
```

But you have to be careful when you are accessing relationships in a collection of models, as each time you'll be performing another query. To prevent this, you can *eager load* relationships using the `with` method like this.

```
$funds = Fund::with('user')->get();
foreach($funds as $fund) {
     echo $fund->user ? $fund->user->name : "na";
}
```